# Ubuntu wont load after showing ubuntu logo

Tags: 14.04

I was upgrading from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.I accidentally shut down the computer mid way through upgrade.Now when i load ubuntu I see ubuntu written on the screen and then nothing happens.Please tell me a way to fix ubuntu .Also I have windows 7 along with ubuntu so I was able to access my files and keep a copy of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 12.04 stuck at boot splash screen](http://askubuntu.com/questions/477247/ubuntu-12-04-stuck-at-boot-splash-screen)

Comment: Can you explain that because I am quiet new to ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Use a live cd if you have it. 
Boot from it and then try to reinstall Ubuntu. 
The Problem could be due to messed up files on the /system folder

Comment: I tried using a live cd but it doesn't recognize 12.04.It asks to create a new partition which I don't want

Comment: Most probably there is no practical OS on your system. It was corrupted due to the accidental shut down. Try doing a fresh install and maybe you could recover your files if they still exist. Let's hope you made a backup before the upgrade.

Comment: And I suggest you use this opportunity to reformat your partition to ext4. It will not be recognised by Windows but will boost the performance on your Linux